# Create ,UPDATE and DELETE call using django-tastypie

Tags: python, sql, django, api, tastypie

I am using django-tastypie to build the API for my project. I followed the [tastypie-doc](http://toastdriven.github.com/django-tastypie/toc.html).

Using this doc I am able to call the GET method and filter the data based on the parameter. But I couldn't find any examples for PUT(UPDATE), DELETE (delete object) and POST(Create a new object).

Does anyone know how to write a call to create, update and delete in django-tastypie?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[post_list](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-tastypie/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=post_list#post-list) and other `post` commands are CREATEs, while `put`s are updates and `delete`s are deletes. There are also `obj_` methods that implement these methods.

You can also take a look at the examples at http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html which show how to do each of the basic actions.

Also, try some general Django tutorials, as they should also provide you with relevant information.